# Live streaming with Replaykit

Tags: ios, swift, broadcast, live-streaming, replaykit

Can I build an application that uses the sharing screen feature of the replaykit. This feature is similar to the Mobcrush application. This means that instead of using 3rd party services like Mocbrush, Youtube, Facebook ... then Can I use my own server to connect with streaming data. Is this feasible?

Comment: Sure it’s possible.

Comment: @szatmary thanks for your comment. Can you send me the documentation or demo about this? I spent many tines on stackoverflow but did not found.

Comment: I am using OpenTok SDK in app. But it can't share screen outside the app :(. It only capture the view then uploading to the server

Comment: @iOSdev did you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `startCapture` and `stopCapture` in `RPScreenRecorder` to record app screen. The handler in `startCapture` will get continuously called to return you the buffer data you need for the live stream.

You can then send that buffer data to your server or a third party streaming service. One example is Wowza, which has an iOS SDK you can integrate.

**RPScreenRecorder Documentation**: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rpscreenrecorder

Wowza: https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-connect-to-wowza-streaming-cloud-with-gocoder-sdk-for-ios 
More streaming options: https://www.quora.com/Which-server-solution-for-a-Live-video-streaming-app

Comment: Can we send stream in real time with RPScreenRecorder?